# would installing a PVC faucet on the Intake pipe by the edge of the lake, to remove the air from it, would cause issue to water pump at other end

Tags: pump, priming

I live in south Florida, and have a water pump that draws water from the lake for irrigation. I changed the intake stop valve in the lake, and tried to prime my pump. It worked fine when I turned it on for the first time. But as soon as I turned it off, I heard loud gurgling  (like an air lock somewhere), and the pump would not work again. I will need to prime it again.

Can I install a PVC faucet at the end of the lake, to use it to fill the intake pipe with water, using city water, to get rid of the air in the intake value (as I suspect has a belly under group that traps air when drained after repair)?

Comment: presumably when you turn off the pump the water drains back to the lake and you have air in the pump. I would install a valve at the intake of the pump and close it before shutting off the pump leaving the pump and pipe under water pressure. Then first turn on the pump then open the valve

Comment: Or install a check valve so water doesn't flow back when the pulp stops, which I believe is what most well pumps do (and which is what my sump pump does).

Comment: Sounds like the intake stop valve (or "foot valve") replacement was not successful, or you have another intake leak somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your hose/pipe intake is too deep in the lake, it may be sucking debris which stops the valve from closing.  You can raise it above the lake bed

- Install a float of some sort (I had a styrofoam alligator for this, but it got stolen)
- Tie with cables to stakes on the bank or
- Strap a hollow concrete block at the end (that was my final solution)

@Traveller has made an excellent suggestion to install a valve at the pump intake.  You close it off before turning the pump off.  If there is a power fail, you are back to square one though.

You can indeed install some sort of faucet with a hose. You just need to make sure it will handle the pressure of the pump.  If its close to the house, you could install a hose socket as well.

Answer (score 0):

I pumped from a lake for irrigation for almost 30 years. Filters and back flow prevention valves are essential to not have constant problems.

You need to install a proper filter such as a [Lake screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DAIXXHQ). Preferably set as to not sit on the bottom.

You then need a [back flow prevention valve.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CY9F4YL) I install mine just below the waterline.  Once installed the pump must be primed, but it should not require another priming again unless there is another issue allowing air to get in . ( that is a separate issue.)
Had been using this method for decades. On average the valve lasts about 2 years and the filter needs cleaning about every 4 months. ( your situation may need a different schedule)